Why can't my `bot.c` file find `jansson.h` MacOS Apple M2
I have this include for my bot.c script:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <jansson.h>

Whenever I try to clang it I get this error:
bot.c:5:10: fatal error: 'jansson.h' file not found
    5 | #include <jansson.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

Curl works, but Jansson doesn't. Here are both of their paths:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jansson/2.14/include/jansson.h
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/curl/8.11.1/include/curl/curl.h

How I compile the code (that works):
clang -I/opt/homebrew/include -o bot bot.c -L/opt/homebrew/lib  -lcurl -ljansson
The way that doesn't work:
clang -o bot bot.c -lcurl -ljansson
My Question:
I know why when I use the-I and -L arguments it works, but how come Curl on its own works when I don't specify the arguments yet Jansson doesn't? I've had this issue in the past with other libraries, and I'd like to know how to solve it.

Which -I arguments did you pass to clang to tell it which directories to look in for headers? (curl is almost certainly getting headers from somewhere else, not the homebrew Cellar location, unless you have one of those directories explicitly added and the other not).

(Bigger picture, how are you compiling your software? Did you create a makefile? Show us the makefile! Are you using autoconf? Writing a clang or gcc command by hand in the terminal? Whatever it is, include it in the question).

Sorry! This is what I'm using to compile:
clang -o bot bot.c -lcurl -ljansson
When I use -I and -L arguments, it works: clang -I/opt/homebrew/include -o bot bot.c -L/opt/homebrew/lib  -lcurl -ljansson
I just want to know why does it have an issue on its own? I've had similar issues before, and I always find it very annoying to find the -I and -L arguments for every single include that doesn't work.

@CharlesDuffy I have no curl directories besides the one in cellar. There's no include folder in the same directory as the project.

@TrendyBananaYT: Please edit the question to include the information about how you compile the code.  The -I option won't find either header unless there is something in /opt/homebrew/include that links to the versioned file paths that you list.

The fact the compiler says “'jansson.h' file not found” indicates that no file named jansson.h is present in any of the directories the compiler searched for the #include <…> directive. The fact you specified -I/opt/homebrew/include means that directory was searched, and therefore jansson.h is not in it. The fact a file named jansson.h is in /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jansson/2.14/include/ is irrelevant to the preceding, as that directory was not searched and likely should not have been. Note that a file may appear in multiple places in a file system…

… by soft/symbolic links, by hard links, or by copies. I suspect stores “original” files in /opt/homebrew/Cellar and puts links or copies in /opt/homebrew/include. You should look in /opt/homebrew/include to see whether jansson.h appears there and what its path relative to /opt/homebrew/include is.

Just because something is in the cellar doesn't mean it's actually installed (by being symlinked from the Homebrew tree). That's the distinction you've run into here: if there's no symlink to that file from the main Homebrew include directory, the janessen package isn't installed; you can use regular homebrew commands to fix that.

@EricPostpischil I have checked /opt/homebrew/include, and there is a jansson.h. It is directly under ./include/.

@CharlesDuffy There are symlinks, though I'm not sure if they are correct. Just to make sure I ran brew unlink jansson and it removed 6 symlinks, and then I relinked it using brew link jansson and it created 6 symlinks. It still can't find the file.

I have found where curl/curl.h is; for some reason, it uses an old XCode directory. I could install jansson to XCode and see if that fixes it, but is there any way to have it work in VSCode and use Homebrew instead of XCode for headers?

Is /opt/homebrew/include/jansson.h readable? If you compile a program containing only #include <jansson.h>, do you get the same error? If you retype the #include line from scratch, do you still get the error? In /opt/homebrew/include/curl/curl.h, insert #error and try compiling a program containing only #include <curl/curl.h>. (This tests whether the compiler is including from the path you think it is.) There are plenty of diagnostic tests you can perform to analyze what is happening.

No, you can't use homebrew "instead" of Xcode - Xcode has your entire SDK, you wouldn't have the C standard library without it. You want to add global include paths, so you can either symlink stuff under /usr/local/{include,lib}, or you can patch LLVM to hardcode your search paths, and then build clang from source...
